# Should the Copy trait always be implemented if possible?

Tags: copy, rust, move

You can implement the `Copy` trait to give the type copy-semantics instead of move-semantics. This can only be done if all its constituent elements (each factor of a product type, or each factor of each variant of a sum-type) are also `Copy`.

This allows you to also make rather large types `Copy`. Can implementing `Copy` be detrimental to performance if the size of the type is "large"?

If `Copy` should always be implemented, why is it not an auto-trait like `Sync` and `Send` for those types which can implement it and have opt-out semantics instead of opt-in?

Comment: [When should my type be Copy?](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Copy.html#when-should-my-type-be-copy)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> why is [`Copy`] not an auto-trait like `Sync` and `Send` for those types which can implement it and have opt-out semantics instead of opt-in?

`Copy` used to be automatically implemented by types that could implement it. This behavior was changed [in December 2014](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/096a28607fb80c91e6e2ca64d9ef44c4e550e96c), not too long before Rust 1.0.

> Should the `Copy` trait always be implemented if possible?

Not necessarily. When developing a library, the choice to implement `Copy` or not on a type has an impact on forward compatibility. Removing a `Copy` implementation on a type is a breaking change (users of that type may rely on the type being copied instead of moved), and as such would impose a major version bump on the library in order to respect [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/). In particular, if a type is able to implement `Copy` now but you think it's possible that the type may evolve such that it could no longer implement `Copy`, you should play it safe and not implement `Copy` on that type.

Another reason for not implementing `Copy` is, as you mentioned, large types. It may be useful to implement only `Clone` for such types, as usually "`Clone` but not `Copy`" indicates that cloning the value is not "cheap". However, even if a type is not `Copy`, one could still cause a large memory copy operation by merely moving the value (though if you're lucky, the compiler might optimize it away).

> Can implementing `Copy` be detrimental to performance if the size of the type is "large"?

Not if you never perform a copy on the type! Keep in mind that the only difference between a *move* and a *copy* is that a move makes the source unusable (i.e. the compiler will raise an error if you try to use a value after it was moved), while a copy doesn't; both operations are implemented as a shallow memory copy.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that even if you know a type could implement `Copy`, you might elect to not do so in order to retain "move" semantics.

Comment: Another thing to note is that non-`Copy` is the *safe* default.  If you're implementing your own version of `Box` by wrapping a raw pointer, such a type *would* be eligible for any sort of implicit `Copy` implementation, which means the programmer would have to actively consider the correctness of `Copy` on every type, and remember to disable it where required.  With the current design, if the programmer forgets to consider `Copy`... nothing happens and nothing breaks.