# Can an assignment result in a potentially expensive deep-copy of a tuple?

Tags: rust

[*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html) states:

> So what types are `Copy`?
>
> [...]
>
> - Tuples, if they only contain types that are also `Copy`. For example, `(i32, i32)` is `Copy`, but `(i32, String)` is not.

Does this mean that an assignment of a tuple with a considerable number of elements that are also `Copy` can result in a potentially expensive deep-copy of a tuple?

In this example, would Rust make a deep copy of the tuple and all of its contents?

```
let tpl = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);  // and many more entries
let tpl2 = tpl;
println!("{:?} {:?}", tpl, tpl2);
```

This seems counter-intuitive for a language that is fast in almost everything it does. Are tuples (of items that are `Copy`) just meant to be short enough that this will not have an impact on performance?

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Should the Copy trait always be implemented if possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46185453/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Specifically: *one could still cause a large memory copy operation by merely moving the value (though if you're lucky, the compiler might optimize it away).*

Comment: For *this* specific case, I'd trust the optimizer until profiling proved me wrong.

Comment: the answer also states: *both operations are implemented as a shallow memory copy*... hmm. i'm guessing my deep-copy thinking is wrong (in general) and the optimizer will be smart about it in some way.

Comment: "shallow" and "deep" don't have strong meaning here. Perhaps you can define what you mean by them?

Comment: ok, you are right. by "deep" i meant that all the elements in the tuple (the 10 integers in my example) are copied.

Comment: Based on the code that you've provided, there's no need for a copy to take place as `tpl` is never used again. In fact, the code you've provided is likely to be completely removed when optimizations are applied. However, **semantically**, the data *might* be moved and it *might* be copied.

Comment: ok, sure, i should have added print statements for both below the assignment. (will do that).

Comment: In rust, when you say `let x = y` you are either copying the entirety of `y` into `x` if it's `Copy`, but if it's not, then it _could_ be moved (And therefore incur a `memcpy`). This is to say, that if I `Copy` something by reassigning it, then I am doing a bitwise copy of the item.

Comment: @OptimisticPeach that's overly simplistic. No copy needs to occur if `y` is never used again. `let x = y` might result in a move even if the type is `Copy`.

Comment: I didn't mean to over exaggerate, I was talking as if we didn't apply any optimizations and the compiler produced assembly exactly as written. In other words, I was talking semantically, which says that `Copy` items _can_ be copied bitwise and non-`Copy` items are moved. It's up to the optimizer to decide if you actually move the value or simply copy it.